# Can I use shuffle = False instead of random_state in KMeans

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

Instead of using:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', random_state = 42)
```

I want to use:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', shuffle = False)
```

Is it OK? or Wrong?

Comment: Did you try the 2nd variant? What did you get? As pointed out in the answer, KMeans does not have a `shuffle` argument, so what *exactly* are you asking here?

Comment: Yes, I tried 2nd variant and it didn't work. I think it is a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its wrong as far as i understand , because there is no such a parameter Shuffle in sklearn for k means
check [K means documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)  for all parameters you need.

To understand better what is random state , you fix its value to reproduce all
calculations you`ve done next time .

Answer (score 0):

In k-means clustering, the initial placement of centroids can affect the final clustering result. By setting the random state to a specific value, you can ensure that the random initialization is consistent across multiple runs of the clustering algorithm. This allows for reproducibility and consistent results.

If you want to remove that it still works but each time there could be different result and hence your variables vary

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++')
```

To prevent this we initialise random state